# Create release without specifying repository

Tags: maven

In my Maven project, I am trying to make a release, but for now I don't want to deploy it anywhere(I will do that later).

I would like the JAR file or whatever is generated because of the release to remain on my local machine, without being deployed anywhere.

I am running this:

```
mvn release:prepare
mvn release:perform
```

The problem is that on the second line I am getting this error:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project my-project: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

What is this about?

I don't have any `distributionManagement` tag in my project and if I would have one, I wouldn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- set the value for the [goals](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#goals) parameter of the maven-release-plugin to `install`
- if you never want to deploy to a remote repository, set the [skip](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#skip) parameter of the maven-deploy-plugin to `true`.

Comment: Where should I place the `<skip>` tag? Under the `maven-deploy-plugin` `<dependency>` it doesn't work.

Comment: In general, all parameters for any maven-plugin can be specified between the `<configuration>`-tags. In your case it is probably better to specify it there instead of specifying it as property, since properties are variables and can be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the code:

```
 <properties>
        <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip> 
 </properties>
```